# How would I delay/debounce a call to a child component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-redux

There are a series of components that will reveal themselves after running a custom method `viewChildRef.show()` on them (I'm using a `@ViewChild` reference).

The problem is that the state gets updated with a `@Select` decorator (angular-redux/store) initially before the child component is ready - the callback in the subscription needs to be called after `ngAfterViewChecked` has triggered.

**What is best practice to delay a call to a child component until a specific hook occurs?** For those that don't know angular-redux/store, I have a rxjs subscription to play with from the @select decorator. Maybe a delay/debounce set up would work?

I can and have already set a variable `readyForShow` that is set to true, and then again false once `ngAfterViewChecked` is called. This is a tedious solution - there must be a better way, and this must be common in the angular-redux world.

**My goal is to have something easily and quickly applied when I need to do this elsewhere as well.**

**Additionally, if there is a ready made solution in ngrx feel free to mention this - it will cause me to consider switching libraries and may help others!**

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, just about every 'real' page will fetch data asynchronously, so I just hook up the template to the observable with the async pipe, let the literal parts display and the async data fill in when it arrives, e.g

```
<span>Last modified: {{ (fileInfo$ | async)?.lastModified }}</span>
```

Note the construct - observable and pipe are bracketed, outside the bracket you have the unwrapped object. The Elvis/Safe navigation operator `?` which stops evaluation of the property when the object is null.

If the page doesn't look right without data, you can hide it with ngIf or ngShow

```
<span *ngIf="(lastRefresh$ | async)">Refreshed</span>
```

Also, with Redux stores the shape of the default/initial store can be important, e.g for an object initialize to {} instead of null, for an array initialize to [] - something that downstream code won't crash on too easily.